# Access Violation Exception in a very small program C#

Tags: c#, access-violation

I am making a small program with some `textboxes` and some `labels` with a `button` and a `webbrowser`. The code is not more than 80 lines and all it contains is a button click event that gives the `webbrowser` a link entered in the textbox and `neviage()` function is called and the second event is the browser's document complete event. The error is as follows

[image]

I have googled and searched on stackoverflow about access violation a lot but i was not able to find anything for my purpose. The exception does not occur at any specific point. It comes up randomly and always at `Application.Run` without any stacktrace!

One thing that is bothering me the most is that the error is occurring in the try block and it is not being caught!

And is there any solution to this exception? I tried going to debug->exceptions->Common Language Runtime Exceptions->System and checking thrown, but it didn't work.

I am a novice programer so forgive my inexperience!

EDIT: Code

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void simpleButton_Go_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate(textEdit_url.Text);
            webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (webBrowser1.Url.ToString().Contains("member/login"))
            {
                if (webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("email_address")!=null)
                {                    
                    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("email_address").SetAttribute("value", textEdit_username.Text);
                    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("member_password").SetAttribute("value", textEdit_password.Text);

                    var c = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button");
                    foreach (HtmlElement element in c)
                    {
                        if (element.InnerText == "Login")
                            element.InvokeMember("click");
                    }
                }
            }
            if (webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("toolbar_login") != null && webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("toolbar_login").InnerText == "Log In")
            {
                webBrowser1.Navigate("www.somesite.com");
            }
            else if (webBrowser1.Url.ToString() == textEdit_url.Text)
            {

                var c = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button");
                foreach (HtmlElement element in c)
                {
                    if (element.InnerText == "Add to this list")
                    {
                        element.InvokeMember("click");

                        var te = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("textarea");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
                webBrowser1.Navigate(textEdit_url.Text);
        }
```

EDIT: Update

As suggested I removed devexpress, made a new winform project, copied the code to that and the error still came. The stacktrace of the new project is

```
 at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at app.Program.Main() in C:\Documents and Settings\admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\app\app\Program.cs:line 18
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: Using F11 and debug points tell u what?

Comment: Post the constructor of Form1.

Comment: Open the Call Stack window and post the stack that shows where the exception *really* occurred.

Comment: Have you tried putting a break point into the constructor for your Form class And stepping through the code.

http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/VSBreakpoints.aspx

It's difficult to tell what exactly is going wrong from the information you have supplied.

Comment: The call stack window has > form1.exe!WindowsApplication1.Program.Main() Line 25 + 0x1d bytes
Only and nothing else

Comment: you need to show your code. Maybe you have something in load method?

Comment: @cadrell0 The constructor only has InitializeComponent() method.

Comment: @Cancer: you need to expand the call stack to include external code (right click - Show external code)

Comment: or click "View details" in the exception, find "StackTrace" and post it here

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint on your InitializeComponent method and step into it. The problem is probably in the initialization of one of your controls

Comment: Very likely there are something wrong with your system. Should try another cleanly built machine.

Answer (score 0):

One of things that could cause the problem is with DevExpress components. I had similar problem - solution was force initialize bar manager. So you can try:

1. Remove DevExpress components and see if it works.
2. Set breakpoint in `InitializeComponent` method(in Form1.Designer.cs file) and step each line, in one of them you should get error. If you find one you could post that line and we could try to reproduce error or try to figure out how to fix it.

Also try to start Visual Studio as Administrator.

Comment: removed devexpress. The error still came. updated the stacktrace of the error.

Comment: Have you tried debug InitializeComponent method? also take a look at [this thread answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/wpf/thread/9974d41a-4384-40fe-8e83-8d62d1d5fc7f)